# Is there a way to get the largest integer one can use in Python?

Tags: python, integer

Is there some pre-defined constant like `INT_MAX`?

Comment: It is 2^31 - 1 in Python 32 and 2^63 - 1 Python 64 bit runtime system.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

Python has arbitrary precision integers so there is no true fixed maximum.  You're only limited by available memory.

In Python 2, there are two types, `int` and `long`.  `int`s use a C type, while `long`s are arbitrary precision.  You can use `sys.maxint` to find the maximum `int`.  But `int`s are automatically promoted to `long`, so you usually don't need to worry about it:

```
sys.maxint + 1
```

works fine and returns a `long`.

`sys.maxint` does not even exist in Python 3, since `int` and `long` were unified into a single arbitrary precision `int` type.

Comment: Note that in Python 3 (and Python 2.6 and up) `sys.maxsize` can be used when you need an arbitrarily-large value.

Comment: is there one that is not a long?

Comment: `sys.maxsize` continues to be the theoretical limit on size of containers for python 2 and 3 (theoretical because memory is the real limiting factor)

Comment: @mattdm `sys.maxsize+1` is larger than that.