# Multiplication of 3 long long numbers gives different answers in C++ and Python

Tags: c++, python, multiplication

```
unsigned long long a,b,c;
cin>>a>>b>>c;
cout<<(a*b*c);
```

Input given: 512 294967268 279632277
Output: 5337484673731225600

However, when I do `512 * 294967268 * 279632277` in Python, the output I get is:

```
42230972821150328832L
```

Why do I get a different answer?

Comment: Overflow obviously. Use `long double` instead. Check out the `sizeof (long long)` and `long double` and you'll see the difference.

Comment: for verification that it is overflow you can try `42230972821150328832%(2**64)` in python and it returns `5337484673731225600L`

Answer (score 6):

Overflow in C++ for sure.

Python has datatype of arbitrary size to store the result. So if the value to be stored is big, the  *size* of the datatype is also big automatically.

```
>> x = 512 * 294967268 * 279632277
>> x
42230972821150328832L
>> type(x)
<type 'long'>
>> x.__sizeof__()
36
>> x = x * x
>> x
1783455065420737763677831948901730484224L
>> type(x)
<type 'long'>
>> x.__sizeof__()
44
```

So practically there is no limit on the size of the datatype. The available memory defines the theoretical limit.

Comment: What usually happens is that integers are promoted to an arbitrary precision integer type when required. More on that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581842/python-integer-ranges).