# Project Euler #13 understandning (Python)

Tags: python

Problem 13: http://projecteuler.net/problem=13

Work out the first ten digits of the sum of the following one-hundred 50-digit numbers.
So, is the question sum the 5000 digits and the answer is the first 10 digits in the result?

```
bignumber = list of the 5000 digits
sum(bignumber) = abcdefghijklmnopqrst...    
answer = abcdefghj
```

Well when I do this `sum(bignumber) = 22660` (which even is not 10 digits)...

have I misread the question?

```
def foo():
    with open ("bignumber", "r") as myfile:
        data=myfile.read().replace('\n', '')
    data = map(long, data)
    datasum = sum(data)
    return (datasum)
```

Comment: The question is to sum the 100 numbers, not to sum their digits.

Comment: It's the difference between 12+34 and 1+2+3+4.

Comment: Note that the question is a bit easier in python, since integers have no maximum: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581842/python-integer-ranges, so you do not have to deal with overflow.

Comment: Lets say someone wanted to do this in another language like C#. How could they overcome the limitations of the ulong being only 20 digits max in length?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are misreading the question.

They give you 100 numbers that you need to sum, each of which is 50 digits long (aka magnitude of X*10^50). The 50 digit part is there so you cant just use traditional int/long data types (As JLLAgrange points out, this part shouldn't be a problem for python since integers have no max value).

Comment: Each number is 50 digits long and there are one-hundred numbers of such length.

Answer (score 0):

Each number is 50 digits long (i.e., each line is a digit).  You might try

```
def foo():
    with open ("bignumber", "r") as myfile:
        data=myfile.read()
    data = map(int, data)
    datasum = sum(data)
    return datasum
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you understood the question correctly, but applied wrongly in Python.

You are doing:

```
with open ("bignumber", "r") as myfile:
    data=myfile.read().replace('\n', '')
    #Now `data` is a big huge string of digits
data = map(long, data)
#Now data is an array of 5000 elements of each digit.
#And then you are trying sum this array of digits.
```

What you need:

```
with open(..) as fileObj:
    data = [long(line.strip()) for line in fileObj]
```

[Look at this example](http://ideone.com/IyzqLA)