# OUTPUT ERROR,The problem is to find the sum 5000 digit number cpp

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, stl

This is the code(cpp)

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <numeric>//to import the accumulate function
    #include <vector>
    #include <algorithm>

    using namespace std;
    int main(){
    vector<long long> vi;
     string s; //this contains the long number its better not to type here
    int k=0,sum=0;
     for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
      k=(int)s[i]-(int)'0';
     cout<<k<<endl;
       vi.push_back(k);
 
      }
      for(int i:vi){
        cout<<i<<endl;
      }
         cout<<accumulate(vi.begin(),vi.end(),0);

    
        }
```

whatever i do i get the answer 22660
i tried using without accumulate still 22660 ,i dont know why this happens

Comment: It's kind of hard to tell why you get 22660 without knowing what the number is.

Comment: Hint:  read the number as a string.  Access the digits like:  `int digit_value = number_as_string[x] - '0';`

Comment: @cigien Summing 5000 digits shouldn't overflow an int.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews That's what he is doing or am I missing something?

Comment: @john oh right, thought Op wanted to convert string to int.

Comment: Anyway the posted code looks OK to me, the error is probably in the part that's been left out.

Comment: @john Due to formatting, I missed that.

Comment: Why are you placing the digit into a `vector` after isolating it?  Why not add the digit to a sum variable directly?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: 22660 is actually a not implausable result from summing 5000 digits, what makes you think it's wrong?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews i tried that still its showing 22660

Comment: @john the answer is 567.......... its a very large number this is a question from project euler question number 13

Comment: @JesperJuhl i was not shouting i forgot to turn off the caps sorry

Comment: You say you know what the input string is, and what the expected result should be. Why don't you share that with us?

Comment: @Vict_rprin_e Read what you wrote before posting it, please. I shouldn't have to say that, it should be an obvious thing to do.

Comment: Let's look at the worst case.  The maximum value for a digit is 9.  The maximum quantity of digits is 5000.  The maximum sum is 9 + 9 + 9 ..., which is the same as 5000*9. and 5000*9 == 45000.  This is clearly less than the maximum range of an int.

Comment: @cigien the input is very large it contains 100 lines of 50 digits

Comment: Please edit your post with  description of the problem.  I searched for "5000 digit sum" and came up with Fibonacci numbers and prime numbers.

Comment: @Vict_rprin_e If the real number is spread over 100 lines it is possible that you are incorporating some non-digits (like whitespace or line endings) into your number?

Comment: You may have a [misunderstanding of the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20124928/project-euler-13-understandning-python).  If this is the same problem, you'll want to sum numbers that are 50 digits in length.  There are 100 of these numbers to sum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you are using `std::vector`.  You could calculate the sum without using the vector:

```
int k=0,sum=0;
for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
{
    k = s[i]-'0';
    sum += k;
}
```

Note:  if you are a little paranoid of the sum value fitting into an integer, you can use an `unsigned integer` since digits can't be negative.