# Is Python incorrectly handling this "arbitrary precision integer"?

Tags: python, arbitrary-precision

Python is supposed to have "arbitrary precision integers," according to the answer in [Python integer ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4581847/3113536).  But this result is plainly *not* arbitrary precision:

```
$ python -c 'print("%d" % (999999999999999999999999/3))'
333333333333333327740928
```

According to [PEP 237](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0237/), `bignum` is arbitrarily large (not just the size of C's `long` type).  And [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) says Python's `bignum` is arbitrary precision.

So why the incorrect result from the above line of code?

Comment: In my box it works as expected, even by increasing the number of 9's

Comment: Well, the problem seems to be only on Python3 and the `print` statement

Comment: Python *does* have arbitrary precision integers. The number your code creates is not an integer.

Comment: a mere `python3 -c "print(999999999999999999999999 / 3)"` would show you the issue immediately (it prints a float instead of integer).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Actually in python3 whenever you divide ints you get float as a result. There is a `//` operator that does integer division:

```
 >>> 999999999999999999999999/3
 3.333333333333333e+23
 >>> 999999999999999999999999//3
 333333333333333333333333

 >>> type(999999999999999999999999/3)
 <class 'float'>
 >>> type(999999999999999999999999//3)
 <class 'int'>
```

This does give the correct arbitrary precision output:

```
 python -c 'print("%d" % (999999999999999999999999//3))' 
 333333333333333333333333
```

#### How to write code compatible with both python 2.2+ and 3.3

This is actually simple, just add:

```
 >>> from __future__ import division
```

this will enable 3.X division in 2.2+ code.

```
>>> from sys import version 
>>> version
'2.7.6 (default, Dec 30 2013, 14:37:40) \n[GCC 4.8.2]'
>>> from __future__ import division 
>>> type(999999999999999999999999//3)
<type 'long'>
>>> type(999999999999999999999999/3)
<type 'float'>
```

Comment: This does give the correct arbitrary precision output:
$ python -c 'print("%d" % (999999999999999999999999//3))'
    333333333333333333333333

Comment: Note that the `//` operator is available *since [Python2.2](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/)* (released around 2001 I believe). So it's *not* a python3 feature.

Comment: @Bakuriu I think what he meant is that in python2 `//` is assumed for `/` between two integers, whereas in python3 you need to call it explicitly.

Comment: @SethMMorton Yes, but it's not really clear from the answer. One might think that, since in python2 the behaviour is different there is no `//` operator. This add a bit of complexity if someone wants to write code compatible with both versions. I just wanted to make clear that using `//` does *not* introduce any problem in this sense.