Pandas does not save dtype int64 as long in mongodb
One of the columns in a oracle table has Integer values which needs to be stored in mongodb as Long. Currently this column has values less than int32 can store. But as a futureproofing we want it to be int64.
Now I am reading table in pandas dataframe and setting dtype for this column as int64. And writing to mongodb as df.to_dict(orient='records'). It is always saving it as int32.
df["MY_INT"] = df["MY_INT"].astype("int64")

or
df["MY_INT"] = df["MY_INT"].astype("Int64")

collection.insert_many(df.to_dict('records'))

We have json validator defined on this column with long as bsontype.
    properties: {
      MY_INT: {
        bsonType: 'long'
      },

What this does is that, it is showing all documents as Failed validation if I apply validator after creation of collection. Worse if I create empty collection with json validator, it will fail the insert itself.
I have tried to apply dtype for every pandas dataframe column specifically.
Checked if the dtype is applied appropriately by printing it out just before the documents are saved. But there seems to be no option except creating a monngo document one by one after encoding values for that columns as Long(number). Which is tedious way and removes the usefulness of writing entire dataframe at one go.

maybe apply a post insert update to the mongodb schema and force the field to be 'long' ? then do the validation ? (NB: am not a mongodb user !)

Does this help:https://stackoverflow.com/a/46699347/2282634
