# Why does round(326542009943320970/2) give an incorrect result in python?

Tags: python

The answer should be `163271004971660485`, but it gives `163271004971660480` as the answer. Using `int(326542009943320970/2)` gives the same incorrect result.

Comment: Did you try `round(326542009943320970//2)` ?

Comment: I'm not so versed in Python, but I found this link to be useful: 
https://realpython.com/python-rounding/

Comment: See also [Python and “arbitrary precision integers”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21031093/python-and-arbitrary-precision-integers)

Comment: Short version of the duplicate: your number is too large to represent as a float, and `/` is floating-point division. You need to start with integer division `//` – `326542009943320970 // 2` is the correct, precise version of the incorrect `int(326542009943320970 / 2)` – then apply rounding manually by adding 1 based on whether the input is even or odd with the help of the `%` operator.

Comment: @Austin no need for`round`, but `//` is indeed important here

Comment: @Austin Thanks, that works. Do you know what causes this problem?

Comment: @noob seems Ry was writing the explanation while you were writing your comment :)

Comment: Please see the linked duplicate.