# Is a Python function stored as an object?

Tags: python

This query is in continuation with [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22604974/python-memory-model-for-this-program) to understand further on this point:

> In the case of functions, you have an object which has certain fields,
>   which contain e. g. the code in terms of bytecode, the number of
>   parameters it has, etc.

My question:

1) How do i visualise a function being represented as an object?(NPE answered this question here)

2) How do i visualise an higher order function being represented as an object?

3) How do i visualise modules being represented  as an object? say 'import operator'

4) Are operators like '+'  '>'  '!='  '==' '='  are also mapped to some object methods? say for expr  'check = 2 < 3', Does this internally call some method of type(2) or type(3) to evaluate '<' operator?

Comment: glglgl -- Seperate query is raised as requested

Comment: I'm assuming you're trying to continue on from some other question. Each question on Stack Overflow is supposed to be self contained. You should make this question legible and easy to understand without having to visit any links. As it stands it is very difficult to tell what your actual question is.

Comment: Everything we process in python is `object`.

Comment: @Sham You failed to explain exactly what is unclear about that. I as well thought it was something completely else what you were asking...

Comment: @g.d.d.c  i modified the query now, can u please re-open this question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**All this is saying is that, in Python, functions are objects like any other.**

For example:

```
In [5]: def f(): pass
```

Now `f` is an object of type `function`:

```
In [6]: type(f)
Out[6]: function
```

If you examine it more closely, it contains a whole bunch of fields:

```
In [7]: dir(f)
Out[7]: 
['__call__',
 ...
 'func_closure',
 'func_code',
 'func_defaults',
 'func_dict',
 'func_doc',
 'func_globals',
 'func_name']
```

To pick one example, `f.func_name` is the function's name:

```
In [8]: f.func_name
Out[8]: 'f'
```

and `f.func_code` contains the code:

```
In [9]: f.func_code
Out[9]: <code object f at 0x11b5ad0, file "<ipython-input-5-87d1450e1c01>", line 1>
```

If you are really curious, you can drill down further:

```
In [10]: dir(f.func_code)
Out[10]: 
['__class__',
 ...
 'co_argcount',
 'co_cellvars',
 'co_code',
 'co_consts',
 'co_filename',
 'co_firstlineno',
 'co_flags',
 'co_freevars',
 'co_lnotab',
 'co_name',
 'co_names',
 'co_nlocals',
 'co_stacksize',
 'co_varnames']
```

and so on.

(The above output was produced using Python 2.7.3.)

Comment: >>> import sys
>>> print(sys.version)
3.2.3 (default, Apr 11 2012, 07:12:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
>>> def doNothing():pass

>>> doNothing.func_name
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#33>", line 1, in <module>
    doNothing.func_name
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'func_name'
>>> doNothing.func_code
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#34>", line 1, in <module>
    doNothing.func_code
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'func_code'

Comment: @Sham: On Python 3, you'll want to use `__name__` and `__code__` instead of `func_name` and `func_code`.

Comment: @Sham You already saw that `dir(doNothing)` shows you what attributes you have. The ones which look like these you are looking for are probably the ones you really want. E. g., you look for `func_code` as it was named on 2.x, you see a `__code__` on 3.x --> you found what you llok for.

Comment: @glglgl If it an higher order function, What attributes do i need t oreview to know the function passed into?