# different answer in javascript and python with large number- Division or mod operator

Tags: javascript, python, google-chrome, firefox, largenumber

when i was dealing with some large numbers like,
take any random number `3289568273632879456235` .

I found that in `Chrome` or `Firefox` `console`
  `3289568273632879456235 % 6 = 0`
but in `Python` shell
 `3289568273632879456235 % 6 = 5`.

after that i found that answer from Python is correct.

so i don't understand why there is different answers.
can anybody explain to me.

Comment: Well clearly python is right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because javascript has no concept of an integer -- only numbers (which are stored as IEEE floats).  Floats have a finite precision, if you try to make a number more precise than the float can represent, it will be "truncated" -- Which is exactly what is happening with your big numbers.  Consider the python "equivalent":

```
>>> int(float(3289568273632879456235)) % 6
0L
```

Here's a few more interesting tidbits to hopefully make the point a little more clear:

```
>>> int(float(3289568273632879456235))  # Notice, the different result due to loss of precision.
3289568273632879706112L
>>> int(float(3289568273632879456235)) == int(float(3289568273632879456236))  # different numbers, same result due to "truncation"
True
```

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript uses IEEE floating point math, which is limited in the numbers it can handle.

There is a length discussion here:

- http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1997934&seqNum=2
- [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Python, on the other hand, uses a different system for handling integers, discussed here

- [Python integer ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581842/python-integer-ranges)