# Is this an infinite loop?

Tags: loops, logic, infinite-loop

Just wanted to confirm whether the following is an infinite loop or not. I think it's not because of how memory works, I faintly remember something about how the ints loop back to the opposite limit once a certain lower or upper limit is reached, based on how ints are stored in a computer's memory. But I'm not certain.

```
i = 0
while i < 1:
    #do stuff
    i -= 1
```

EDIT: my god a stupid mistake in the syntax, my bad, I've edited the code now. Thanks for the patience. :)

Comment: If you're asking about a specific language or machine, please specify.

Comment: Yes, because the condition `i < 1` never becomes `true`, unless in the `#do stuff` part that you didn't show you are modifying the variable `i` so that it might become less than 1. Note: you are decrementing a different variable `j`. Did you mean to do this or did you really mean `i`?

Comment: @Jesper yeah my bad, I meant `i`.

Comment: @JoshLee um, not really. Just in general.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is an infinite loop.

Your condition is `while i < 1` and `i` never changes

Comment: just in case, it's a typo on his side.

Comment: In that case is still and infinite loop... I guess that depending of the programming language (and the type of `i`) it could reach the minimum possible value for `i` and throw an error.

Comment: @Dazak hm okay! Considering python 3.x and `i` thus being an `int`?

Comment: According with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4581847/5602069), _Python has arbitrary precision integers so there is no true fixed maximum. You're only limited by available memory_ so it still being an infinite loop, but when the available memory get fill, it will throw an `OverflowError` (in this part I'm guessing since I am not familiar with python)