# How to check if a given number is a power of two?

Tags: python

The code below isn't working right for some inputs.

```py
a, i = set(), 1
while i <= 10000:
    a.add(i)
    i <<= 1

N = int(input())
if N in a:
    print("True")
else:
    print("False")
```

My initial idea was to check for each input if it's a power of 2 by starting from 1 and multiplying by 2 until exceeding the input number, comparing at each step. Instead, I store all the powers of 2 in a `set` beforehand, in order to check a given input in `O(1)`. How can this be improved?

Answer (score 179, accepted):

### Bit Manipulations

One approach would be to use ***bit manipulations***:

```
(n & (n-1) == 0) and n != 0
```

***Explanation:*** every power of 2 has exactly 1 bit set to 1 (the bit in that number's log base-2 index). So when subtracting 1 from it, that bit flips to 0 and all preceding bits flip to 1. That makes these 2 numbers the inverse of each other so when AND-ing them, we will get 0 as the result.

For example:

```
                    n = 8

decimal |   8 = 2**3   |  8 - 1 = 7   |   8 & 7 = 0
        |          ^   |              |
binary  |   1 0 0 0    |   0 1 1 1    |    1 0 0 0
        |   ^          |              |  & 0 1 1 1
index   |   3 2 1 0    |              |    -------
                                           0 0 0 0
-----------------------------------------------------
                    n = 5

decimal | 5 = 2**2 + 1 |  5 - 1 = 4   |   5 & 4 = 4
        |              |              |
binary  |    1 0 1     |    1 0 0     |    1 0 1
        |              |              |  & 1 0 0
index   |    2 1 0     |              |    ------
                                           1 0 0
```

So, in conclusion, whenever we subtract one from a number, AND the result with the number itself, and that becomes 0 - that number is a power of 2!

Of course, AND-ing anything with `0` will give 0, so we add the check for `n != 0`.

---

### `math` functions

You could always use math functions, but notice that using them without care ***could cause incorrect results***:

- [`math.log(x[, base])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.log) with `base=2`:

  ```py
  import math

  math.log(n, 2).is_integer()
  ```
- [`math.log2(x)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.log2):

  ```py
  math.log2(n).is_integer()
  ```

Worth noting that for any `n <= 0`, both functions will throw a `ValueError` as it is mathematically undefined (and therefore shouldn't present a logical problem).

- [`math.frexp(x)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.frexp):

  ```
  abs(math.frexp(n)[0]) == 0.5
  ```

As noted above, for some numbers these functions are not accurate and actually give **FALSE RESULTS**:

- `math.log(2**29, 2).is_integer()` will give `False`
- `math.log2(2**49-1).is_integer()` will give `True`
- `math.frexp(2**53+1)[0] == 0.5` will give `True`!!

This is because `math` functions use floats, and those have an [inherent accuracy problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).

---

### (Expanded) Timing

Some time has passed since this question was asked and some new answers came up with the years. I decided to expand the timing to include all of them.

According to the [math docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#power-and-logarithmic-functions), the `log` with a given base, actually calculates `log(x)/log(base)` which is obviously slow. `log2` is said to be more accurate, and probably more efficient. Bit manipulations are simple operations, not calling any functions.

So the results are:

> [Ev](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70272634/6045800): 0.28 sec
>
> `log` with `base=2`: 0.26 sec
>
> [count_1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69205309/6045800): 0.21 sec
>
> [check_1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57026203/6045800): 0.2 sec
>
> `frexp`: 0.19 sec
>
> `log2`: 0.1 sec
>
> **bit ops: 0.08 sec**

The code I used for these measures can be recreated [in this REPL](https://onlinegdb.com/734nDC_p9) (forked from [this one](https://onlinegdb.com/rytCink8w)).

Comment: Given that `2 ** math.inf == math.inf` and `2 ** -math.inf == 0`, both of which are correct, perhaps we need `or (n == math.inf)` instead of `and (n != 0)`. Note that the fact that `math.inf` is of type `float` in Python, and is not of type `int`, doesn't speak to its mathematical nature which doesn't constrain its numerical type.

Comment: I very much like that answer!

Answer (score 29):

Refer to the excellent and detailed [answer to "How to check if a number is a power of 2"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/600306/7861581) — for C#. The equivalent Python implementation, also using the ["bitwise and" operator `&`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators), is this:

```
def is_power_of_two(n):
    return (n != 0) and (n & (n-1) == 0)
```

As [Python has arbitrary-precision integers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4581847/7861581), this works for any integer `n` as long as it fits into memory.

To summarize briefly the answer cited above: The first term, before the logical `and` operator, simply checks if `n` isn't 0 — and hence *not* a power of 2. The second term checks if it's a power of 2 by making sure that *all* bits after that bitwise `&` operation are 0. The bitwise operation is designed to be only `True` for powers of 2 — with one exception: if `n` (and thus all of its bits) were 0 to begin with.

To add to this: As the [logical `and` "short-circuits"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not) the evaluation of the two terms, it would be more efficient to reverse their order if, in a particular use case, it is *less likely* that a given `n` be 0 than it being a power of 2.

Comment: Given that `2 ** math.inf == math.inf` and `2 ** -math.inf == 0`, both of which are correct, perhaps we need `(n == math.inf) or` instead of `(n != 0) and`. Note that the fact that `math.inf` is of type `float` in Python, and is not of type `int`, doesn't speak to its mathematical nature which doesn't constrain its numerical type.

Answer (score 10):

In binary representation, a power of 2 is a 1 (one) followed by zeros. So if the binary representation of the number has a single 1, then it's a power of 2. No need here to check `num != 0`:

```
print(1 == bin(num).count("1"))
```

Comment: Yes looks simply beautiful +1 but the only problem is its 10X slower than `(n & (n-1) == 0) and n != 0`

Answer (score 6):

[In python 3.10](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html#other-language-changes), [`int.bit_count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.bit_count) counts the set bits of a number, so we can use:

```py
n.bit_count() == 1
```

Answer (score 2):

The `bin` builtin returns a string `"0b1[01]?"` (regex notation) for every strictly positive integer (if system memory suffices, that is), so that we can write the Boolean expression

```
'1' not in bin(abs(n))[3:]
```

that yields `True` for `n` that equals `0`, `1` and `2**k`.

`1` is `2**0` so it is unquestionably a power of two, but `0` is not, unless you take into account the limit of `x=2**k` for `k → -∞`.  Under the second assumption we can write simply

```
check0 = lambda n: '1' not in bin(abs(n))[3:]
```

and under the first one (excluding `0`)

```
check1 = lambda n: '1' not in bin(abs(n))[3:] and n != 0
```

<sup><sub>Of course the solution here proposed  is just one of the many possible ones that

you can use to check if a number is a power of two... and for sure not the most

efficient one but I'm posting it in the sake of completeness :-)</sub></sup>

Answer (score 2):

*Note: this should be a comment on Tomerikoo's answer (currently the most upvoted) but unfortunately Stack Overflow won't let me comment due to reputation points.*

Tomerikoo's answer is very well explained and thought-out. While it covers most applications, but I believe needs a slight modification to make it more robust against a trivial case. Their answer is:

```py
(n & (n-1) == 0) and n != 0
```

The second half checks if the input is an actual 0 which would invalidate the bitwise-and logic. There is another one trivial case when this could happen: input is 1 and the bitwise-and takes place with 0 again, just on the second term. Strictly speaking, `2^0=1` of course but I doubt that it's useful for most applications. A trivial modification to account for that would be:

```py
(n & (n-1) == 0) and (n != 0 and n-1 != 0)
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, `1 = 2^0` is a power of 2 - but I agree that this is an edge case that might be important depending on the use case.

Comment: You are right @CallMeStag and perhaps I was tunnel-visioning for my own application (the next step for me was to expand upon this and if provided integer wasn't already a power of 2, find the next higher number that is). Edited a bit for calrity.

Comment: @CallMeStag makes sense but to say like that 1 is power of all number `1=C^0`

Answer (score 2):

The following code checks whether n is a power of 2 or not:

```
def power_of_two(n):
    count = 0
    st = str(bin(n))
    st = st[2:]

    for i in range(0,len(st)):
        if(st[i] == '1'):
            count += 1
        
    if(count == 1):
        print("True")
    else:
        print("False")
```

Many beginners won't know how code like `(n != 0) and (n & (n-1) == 0)` works.
But if we want to check whether a number is a power of 2 or not, we can convert the number to binary format and see it pretty clearly.

For Example:

```
      ^ (to the power of)

2^0 = 1    (Bin Value : 0000 0001)  
2^1 = 2    (Bin Value : 0000 0010)  
2^2 = 4    (Bin Value : 0000 0100)
2^3 = 8    (Bin Value : 0000 1000)
2^4 = 16   (Bin Value : 0001 0000)
2^5 = 32   (Bin Value : 0010 0000)
2^6 = 64   (Bin Value : 0100 0000)
2^7 = 128  (Bin Value : 1000 0000)
```

If you look at the binary values of all powers of 2, you can see that there is **only one bit `True`**. That's the logic in this program.

So If we count the number of 1 bit's in a binary number and if it is equal to 1, then the given number is power of 2, otherwise it is not.

Answer (score 2):

```
n = int(input())
if '1' in list(bin(n))[3:]: #also can use if '1' in bin(n)[3:]  OR can also use format(n, 'b')[1:]
    print("False")
else:
    print("True")
```

For every number which is power of 2 say(N = 2^n), where n = +integer `bin(N)=bin(2^(+int))` will have string of `form: 0b10000000` e.i 0b1.....zero only if not 0, N is not power of 2.

Also,  `format(n, 'b')` returns `bin(n)[2:]` so can be used

- [**Source**](https://docs.python.org/3/)

  ```
  >>> format(14, '#b'), format(14, 'b')
  ('0b1110', '1110')
  >>> f'{14:#b}', f'{14:b}'
  ('0b1110', '1110')
  ```

Comment: It's the same as [this existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57026203/2745495). `bin` returns a str, and you can use `in` and slicing on a str, without converting to a list. Also, if you want to add explanations, please use the [Edit] link under your answer to include the explanation/descriptions _into the answer_, _not in the comments_.

Answer (score 1):

Use *2 instead of bit shifts. Multiplication or addition are much more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the above answers use `bin()` of `format(int(input()), "b")`

The below code also works: **`Ev(x)` returns True if `x` is  power of 2**

```py
# Ev(x) ~ ispoweroftwo(x)
def Ev(x):
    if x==2:        return True
    elif x%2:       return False
    return Ev(x//2)
```

The above code is based on generating `bin()`

```py
#This function returns binary of integers
def binary(x):
        a = ""
        while x!= 0:
                a += str(x%2)
                x = x//2
        return a[::-1]

I = int(input())
print(format(I, "b")) # To cross-check if equal of not
print(binary(I))
```

I have tried to add my answer because I found what we are doing using `bin(x)[3:]` or `format(x, "b")` is almost like asking the boolean answer of whether or not a given number `x` is divisible by two.....and we keep asking the same

Comment: The only reason I have added the answer is that when I was solving this  wonderful obsessive problem of whether or not a given number is the power of two then I found `bin()` is the only function to make code optimized but later I wanted to find the same for `ispowerofthree()` I don't if there is any function like `trinary()`