# How do I break an infinite Python loop?

Tags: python

I'm looking to fix the following code, so that it can finish successfully for all numbers listed. How can I break the infinite loop that's present?
Furthermore, how can I return print(is_power_of_two(8)) as True?

```
  # Check if the number can be divided by two without a remainder
  while n % 2 == 0:
    n = n / 2
  # If after dividing by two the number is 1, it's a power of two
  if n == 1:
    return True
  return False


print(is_power_of_two(0)) # Should be False
print(is_power_of_two(1)) # Should be True
print(is_power_of_two(8)) # Should be True
print(is_power_of_two(9)) # Should be False
```

Comment: Could you fix indentation in your code sample?

Comment: the `break` is in a spot where it doesn't make any sense. Move it into the loop.

Comment: @Z4-tier code has been set to its default value. Where is break placed?

Comment: For which number(s) do you get an infinite loop? What is your best explanation of why?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I suppose for the odd number? I am not sure.

Comment: Well, what happens if you try testing them one at a time, instead of all at once?

Comment: I get true or false. They're all rendering correctly except for 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your while condition should be :

```
# Check if the number can be divided by two without a remainder
  while n % 2 == 0 and n >1:
    n = n / 2
```

cause for the moment your code infinitely loops when n=1 cause 1%2 = 1

Comment: Loop is not needed there at all.

Comment: for sure, it was to fit his example, i'm not aware either at all with his calc method

Comment: this stops the loop, but I still need to check if a number is a power of 2 within this function.

Comment: This works @lamourettejean-baptiste, except it still returns (is_power_of_two(8)) as False.

Comment: yeah, that's because that's not the correct method to check if number is a power of two. I just acted to break your infinite loop.
You juste got to return  what @ThomasDenisReyes answers instead of making a while loop

Comment: @Sean, you're trying to reinvent [logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm).

Comment: Trying, and failing!

Comment: "Not quite. Remember that the goal of the function is to
check if a number is a power of 2. You need to fix the
infinite loop and still return the correct result."

Comment: Error on line 3:
    while n % 2 == 0 && n > 1:
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: replace it with
while n % 2 == 0 and n > 1:

Comment: Just figured that out too! It works. Thanks @lamourettejean-baptiste.

Answer (score 1):

Add `and n != 0` to the while condition, so the loop will halt when n is zero.

Comment: I think, he doesn't need loop at all.

Comment: where does that go?

Answer (score 1):

```py
def is_power_of_two(n):
  # Check if the number can be divided by two without a remainder
  while n!=0 and (n % 2 == 0 or 2%n==0):
    n = n / 2
    return True
  return False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import math    
math.log2(number).is_integer()
```

Use this. From [Check if a given number is power of two in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57025836/check-if-a-given-number-is-power-of-two-in-python/57025941)

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_power_of_two(n):

 #Check Number for Zero
  if n==0:
    return False
  else:
    # Check if the number can be divided by two without a remainder
    while n % 2 == 0:
      n = n / 2 
    # If after dividing by two the number is 1, it's a power of two
    if n == 1:
      return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_power_of_two(n):
  # Check if the number can be divided by two without a remainder
  while n % 2 == 0 and n!=0:
    n = n / 2
  # If after dividing by two the number is 1, it's a power of two
  if n == 1:
    return True
  return False
  

print(is_power_of_two(0)) # Should be False
print(is_power_of_two(1)) # Should be True
print(is_power_of_two(8)) # Should be True
print(is_power_of_two(9)) # Should be False
```