# Leetcode Different Results Compiling (#231 Power of Two)

Tags: python

I'm working on [this](https://leetcode.com/problems/power-of-two/) leetcode problem.

I am using print statements to debug my failing testcase (536870912).

When hardcoding the values directly `(print(str(29.0 % 1 == 0)))` I obtain the desired, correct result `(True)`.

However, when using the num variable `(num = 29.0)`, I do not obtain the correct result even though the logic should be the exact same `(print(str(num % 1 == 0))) (False)`.

Any tips appreciated... I'm not really sure how to debug this one.

```
import math

class Solution(object):
    def isPowerOfTwo(self, n):
        """
        :type n: int
        :rtype: bool
        """
        # the only case 'log' can't check is '2**0'
        # so weed that out in a check
        if (n == 1):
            return True
        
        # this is a clever application of modulus
        # I'm not sure I would've figured out
        
        num = math.log(n, 2)
        print(str(num))
        is_pow_2 = (num % 1 == 0)
        print(str(is_pow_2))
        print(str(29.0 % 1 == 0))
        
        return (num % 1 == 0)
```

Comment: When I print num, I see `29.000000000000004`, as log2 doesn't return the exact value, you can't use that way. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: `num = math.log(n, 2)` is going to give you a `float` object, which will not necessarily give you numerically exact results

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if a given number is a power of two in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57025836/how-to-check-if-a-given-number-is-a-power-of-two-in-python)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `math`. The standard solution for power of two is through bitwise:

```
class Solution:
    def isPowerOfTwo(self, n):
        if n < 1:
            return False
        while not n & 1:
            n >>= 1

        return n == 1
```

---

### References

- For additional details, you can see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/power-of-two/discuss/). There are plenty of accepted solutions with a variety of [languages](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-) and explanations, efficient algorithms, as well as asymptotic [time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)/[space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity) complexity analysis<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms)</sup> in there.