# How to iterate through *distinct* flags in an enum Flag subclass?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an `enum` to represent distinct subsets of a dataset, *and combinations* of those subsets:

```
from enum import Flag, auto

class DataSubset(Flag):
    TRAIN = auto()
    TEST = auto()
    VALIDATION = auto()
    EXCLUDED = auto()

    TRAIN_TEST = TRAIN | TEST
    ALL_INCLUDED = TRAIN_TEST | VALIDATION
    ALL = ALL_INCLUDED | EXCLUDED
```

Is there a way to iterate through just the distinct flags, but *not* the named combinations? i.e.:

```
[DataSubset.TRAIN, DataSubset.TEST, DataSubset.VALIDATION, DataSubset.EXCLUDED]
```

The goal is to be able to do something like this:

```
def get_subsets(subset):
    return [sub for sub in DataSubset.distinct_flags if sub in subset]
```

and then:

```
>>> get_subsets(DataSubset.TRAIN)
[DataSubset.TRAIN]
>>> get_subsets(DataSubset.TRAIN_TEST)
[DataSubset.TRAIN, DataSubset.TEST]
>>> get_subsets(DataSubset.ALL)
[DataSubset.TRAIN, DataSubset.TEST, DataSubset.VALIDATION, DataSubset.EXCLUDED]
```

Answer (score 2):

Kind of a silly solution, but you can use [the Bit Twiddling Hacks test for integers being a power of 2](https://graphics.stanford.edu/%7Eseander/bithacks.html#DetermineIfPowerOf2) to find only single bit flags. If you have flags that are aliases of existing flags, not combinations of them, this will include them, but it will filter out any flag that doesn't set precisely one bit:

```
def distinct_flags(enm):
    return [x for x in enm if (x.value & (x.value - 1)) == 0]
```

which when used gets the following results (slightly prettier since I ran it in IPython):

```
>>> distinct_flags(DataSubset)
[<DataSubset.TRAIN: 1>,
 <DataSubset.TEST: 2>,
 <DataSubset.VALIDATION: 4>,
 <DataSubset.EXCLUDED: 8>]
```

You'd just build your `get_subsets` function around that functionality or merge both bits of functionality (filtering to single flags and to ones included in the subset provided) into the `if` condition in your existing code.

Answer (score 1):

[Python 3.11](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/enum.html#enum.Flag) can iterate members of a Flag value out of the box, and is careful to exclude aliases.  So it isn't necessary to find a solution for iteration of the distinct definitions.

```
>>> list(DataSubset.TRAIN)
[<DataSubset.TRAIN: 1>]
>>> list(DataSubset.TRAIN_TEST)
[<DataSubset.TRAIN: 1>, <DataSubset.TEST: 2>]
>>> list(DataSubset.ALL)
[<DataSubset.TRAIN: 1>, <DataSubset.TEST: 2>, <DataSubset.VALIDATION: 4>, <DataSubset.EXCLUDED: 8>]
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this by creating a new metaclass, incorporating [this answer on getting powers of 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57025941/1274721) and [this answer on changing iterating behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64579302/1274721)

```
from enum import EnumMeta, Flag, auto

class DistinctFlag(EnumMeta):
    def __iter__(cls):
        for x in super().__iter__():
            if (x.value & (x.value-1))==0 and x.value != 0:
                yield x

                
class DataSubset(Flag, metaclass=DistinctFlag):
    """Enum to describe distinct subsets of a modeling dataset"""
    BURN_IN = auto()
    TRAIN = auto()
    TEST = auto()
    HOLDOUT = auto()
    EXCLUDED = auto()
    
    TRAIN_TEST = TRAIN | TEST
    OBS = BURN_IN | TRAIN_TEST
    ALL_INCLUDED = OBS | HOLDOUT
    ALL = ALL_INCLUDED | EXCLUDED
```

So then:

```
>>> print(list(DataSubset)
[<DataSubset.BURN_IN: 1>,
 <DataSubset.TRAIN: 2>,
 <DataSubset.TEST: 4>,
 <DataSubset.HOLDOUT: 8>,
 <DataSubset.EXCLUDED: 16>]
```

Comment: Note: You don't need the `and x.value != 0` part of your test for the case where all flags are created with `auto()` or a combination of said flags, as `auto()` for flags starts from `1`; no single flag would have a value of `0` (this isn't just implementation detail, it's a logical requirement; otherwise, every flag would be implicitly unioned with the flag with value `0`).