# How to override iteration behavior of a enum Flag subclass?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to override iteration behavior for a `Flag` `enum`:

```
from enum import Flag, auto

class MyFlags(Flag):
    A = auto()
    B = auto()
    C = auto()
    
    D = A | C

    def __iter__(self):
       for x in super().__iter__():
           if x.value % 2 == 0:
                yield x
```

But it seems the `__iter__` is never actually called:

```
>>> list(MyFlags)
[MyFlags.A, MyFlags.B, MyFlags.C, MyFlags.D]
```

How can I override iteration behavior here?

Comment: `__iter__(self)` is for an instance object, you're calling it on the class itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sublass `EnumMeta` and then add `metaclass=` to your Enum class:

```
from enum import Flag, EnumMeta, auto


class MyEnumMeta(EnumMeta):
    def __iter__(self):
       for x in super().__iter__():
           if x.value % 2 == 0:
                yield x


class MyFlags(Flag, metaclass=MyEnumMeta):
    A = auto()
    B = auto()
    C = auto()
    
    D = A | C


print(list(MyFlags))
```

Prints:

```
[<MyFlags.B: 2>, <MyFlags.C: 4>]
```