# How to create a multi-bot tournament style Rock Paper Scissors game in Python

Tags: python

I am a beginner Python programmer and my professor assigned this interestingly challenging assignment...

The assignment is to create a rock, paper, scissors game that is only played by the computer. The user has to input a number at the start to denotate how many bots will be in the game, and from there, the game will run in a bracket tournament style until there is one winner. I sat on this for quite some time and I am not really sure where to start. I don't just want the answer, I just need a little push in the right direction haha. I wrote the basic code of asking the player for the input and checking if it is a number or not, then assigning it to a variable. Really I just am not sure how to create a "player" for x amount, and put them in a bracket style tournament and then run them against each other (which is almost all of it haha)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, "amount" is a phrase used for uncountable things, like milk or fire. For countable things like players or lazy university students, you can use "number of" instead.

"create a "player" for x amount"

1. Make a create_player(player_name) function
2. Call that function in a for loop that runs x times

"put them in a bracket style tournament"

1. Look into [Array Representation Of Binary Heap](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/array-representation-of-binary-heap/)
2. You can then make the lowest leafs play against each other until the tree has only its root left

"and then run them against each other"

1. make a which_player_wins(player_1, player_2) function
2. keep calling that function until one of them wins

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a bracket tournament style, you should first check that the number the user inputs is a power of two. You can do this with the following code:

```
n = int(input("Please enter the number of players: "))
while (n & (n-1) != 0) or n == 0:
    print("The number of players is not valid to play a brackets style tornurament!\nValue must be power of 2.\n")
    n = int(input("Please enter the number of players: "))
```

You can learn more about how this works [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57025941/11698501). Note that it also checks that the number of players isn´t negative.

You can then use a random function to simulate the rock, scissors, paper game. The following function simulates a single game:

```
import random

def rock_paper_scissors_game():
    actions = ["paper", "rock", "scissors"]
    p1_choice = random.choice(actions)
    p2_choice = random.choice(actions)
    if p1_choice == p2_choice:
        print(f"Both players selected {p1_choice}. It's a tie!")
    elif p1_choice == "rock":
        if p2_choice == "scissors":
            print("Rock smashes scissors! Player 1 wins!")
        else:
            print("Paper covers rock! Player 2 wins!")
    elif p1_choice == "paper":
        if p2_choice == "rock":
            print("Paper covers rock! Player 1 wins!")
        else:
            print("Scissors cuts paper! Player 2 wins!")
    elif p1_choice == "scissors":
        if p2_choice == "paper":
            print("Scissors cuts paper! Player 1 wins!")
        else:
            print("Rock smashes scissors! Player 2 wins!")
```

You can then call this function each time a game is played and simulate the tournament.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by creating a player class that has all of the methods/logic an automated player would need.  Next create a game method that takes two of these player classes and decides the winner.  Finally instantiate an array/list of length N of player objects, and feed that into the game method.